# extjs and reloading all other store upon adding / editing a record

Tags: extjs

I have a grid with several stores.. Some of the stores are linked to certain grids and stores that contain selects they are linked too...

i'd like to refresh all stores if i add / edit / delete a record in certain stores..

I currently have hardcoded my store names, but i like to transform this to a dynamic method, since i want my store names to be dynamic...

I can't seem to find out how to get a list so i can loop through the stores and reload them,  or just reload them with a singe command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your stores have an identifier, you could use [Ext.data.StoreManager.each()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.StoreManager-method-each) to loop through all the registered stores.

If you're using MVC, however, a better approach might be to announce the firing of a custom, global event that could be listened to within your controllers, which could then manage the refreshing on a component-by-component level. The advantage of this would be you would have more granular control over which stores are getting reloaded, as opposed to the brute force of using StoreManager.each().

Comment: i've been trying to use it, but i'm not doing it right..
Ext.data.StoreManager.each(
     function(item,index,len){
      console.log(index);
     }
    );
that only returns one record as well as 
Ext.each(Ext.data.StoreManager,
     function(item,index,len){
      console.log(index);
     }
    );

Comment: Do you have storeIds on the stores you want to reload?